# Como corregir warning de sintaxis descontinuada en jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

Estoy haciendo un sistema web en .Net 6 MVC y C#, en una validacion que hago checo dos cantidades "**Rate Minimo**" y "**Rate Maximo**", cuando el "**Rate Minimo**" es mayor al "**Rate Maximo**", disparo una alerta y vuelvo a asignar el "focus" al input "**Rate Minimo**", todo funciona bien, pero Visual Studio 2022 marca el siguiente warning

[image: warning VS 2022]

indicando que `$("#VacancyRateMin").focus();` esta descontinuada, pero no se como debe ser la nueva forma o como hacerlo para que no marque el warning.

```
    $("#VacancyRateMax").on('blur', function () {
        let rateMin = parseFloat($("#VacancyRateMin").val());
        let rateMax = parseFloat($("#VacancyRateMax").val());

        if (rateMin > rateMax) {
            Swal.fire({
                text: "Rate Minium (" + rateMin + ") cannot be grether than Rate Maximum (" + rateMax + ")",
                icon: 'error',
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                timer: 3000,
                timerProgressBar: true
            }).then(() => {
                // Aquí la alerta se ha cerrado
                $("#VacancyRateMin").focus();
            });
        }
    });
```

Muchas gracias por su apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer lo que indica la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/focus-shorthand/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$("#VacancyRateMin").trigger( "focus" );
```

Comment: Muchisismas gracias Yussef, la verdad busque en muchos lados pero no encontre la informacion.

Comment: @LuisGerardo Estaba medio escondido el mensaje, a mi también me costo verlo. Saludos y suerte con tu proyecto